# How to set a value as selected in custom admin form?

Tags: magento-1.8, adminform

I have an admin form with following field

```
$author = Mage::helper('blog/post')->getDefaultAuthorId();

    $fieldset->addField('post_author', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sprung_blog')->__('Author'),
        'name'  => 'post_author',
        'required'  => true,
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'value' => $author,
        'values'=> Mage::getModel('sprung_blog/post_attribute_source_postauthor')->getAllOptions(true),
    ));
```

Postauthor.php file contains following

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false){

$collection = Mage::getModel('blog/author')->getCollection();

$options = array(array('value'=>'', 'label'=>'Please Select Author'));

foreach ($collection as $cat){

    $options[] = array('value'=>$cat['entity_id'],'label'=>$cat['author_name']);
}   
return $options;
```

}

Here, I have one author as selected default from admin configuration. So when i add a new post , "post_author" field i need to display the default user id as selected. After setting 'value' also its not showing as selected in admin form.Please help

Comment: try clearing your cache

Comment: Yeah, I have done everything. But its not coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added following code to _prepareForm()

```
$formValues = Mage::registry('current_post')->getDefaultValues();
    if (!is_array($formValues)){
        $formValues = array();
    }
    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getPostData()){
        $formValues = array_merge($formValues, Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getPostData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setPostData(null);
    }
    elseif (Mage::registry('current_post')){
        $formValues = array_merge($formValues, Mage::registry('current_post')->getData());
    }
```

/* My code start here */

```
    $author = Mage::helper('sprung_blog/post')->getDefaultAuthorId();

    if(empty($formValues['post_author'])){

        $formValues['post_author'] = $author;;

    }

    $form->setValues($formValues);
```

and field changed to

```
 $fieldset->addField('post_author', 'select', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Author'),
    'name'  => 'post_author',
    'required'  => true,
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'values'=> Mage::getModel('sprung_blog/post_attribute_source_postauthor')->getAllOptions(true),
));
```

Now it works fine..